# How to find Chromium build number?

Tags: chromium

I would like to find the binary for Chromium 70.0.3522.0.

The binaries are [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/) (linked from [here](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)) and the source is [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/70.0.3522.0) but so far I was unable to match up the build numbers.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code ?